# Regex that will match text before a left-parentheses, but not the left parentheses itself

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write some RegEx that will only match the word directly in front of it, like this:

```
function myFunction () {
  //code
}
```

What I'm trying to get is what's being used to highlight `myFunction`. The code that I've been trying is `^[^\(]*`, but it matches with everything in front of the left parentheses, not just the word in front of it.

Comment: Your attempt has no resemblance whatsoever to what you're trying to accomplish. Can you at least explain what you think this regex `\^[^/]+` should do in relation to the goal of matching `myFunction`?

Comment: @blhsing I realized my mistake and edited my question to actually make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
\S+(?=\s*\())
```

- `\S+` non-whitespace characters
- `(?=...)` positive lookahead
- `\s*\(` any whitespace followed by a `(`

See the [proof](https://regex101.com/r/P2noIs/1/)